# How to autofill authentication popup

Tags: html, authentication, basic-authentication

I have a link for example:

```
www.site.com
```

When I click on it the site has an authentication requirement. Is there anyway I can engineer the link so that the username and password are automatically filled in so I don't have to enter these details such as:

```
www.site.com?username="jim"&password="qwerty"
```

I was considering http headers but not sure how to implement or whether it is possible.

Comment: This used to be possible by putting username and passwort into the URL, but browsers no longer support it, and it's a bad idea anyway because the credentials would show up in the browser history, etc.

Comment: ... although you *may* be able to indeed do something with the headers. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507234/how-to-use-basic-auth-with-jquery-and-ajax for how to authenticate through Ajax. That *should* log the user in, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: Its for a basic test so I was indeed able to pass the username and password in the url like this http://username:password@www.site.com. I understand its not the most secure but for basic testing it did the job. Thanks for the info guys. Much appreciated.